# Classic ASP page - Detect if page is refreshed or redirected from another page

Tags: asp-classic, page-refresh

I am working on a Classic ASP application hosted on IIS 6.  User can enter the details in Enter_details.asp page and click on send email button to receive email confirmation.  After clicking on Send email button, page is redirected to email.asp page and email is sent.

If users refresh the email.asp page, a duplicate email is sent with the same details. How to check if an ASP page is redirected or refreshed and avoid duplicate emails?

**Page1: Enter_Details.asp page**

```
<form action="email.asp" method="POST">

<input type="Submit" name="Submitbutton" value="Send E-Mail">
```

**Page 2: Email.asp**

`code to send email goes here.`

What i want is to alert the user if an email is already sent.

How to check if an ASP page is redirected or refreshed?

Comment: A simple logic for accomplish this task is to show a pop up(with only Ok button) message to user as "Mail sent successfully........" , upon clicking ok button, redirect the user away from `email.asp` to either home page or to inbox page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page the user ends up on shouldn't be the one to actually do the emailing.

In your situation, `Enter_details.asp` submits data to `email.asp`, which does the emailing, *and* tells the user the email has been sent. Hence, if it is reloaded, both actions will be repeated.

If you leave the emailing functionality where it is in `email.asp`, and when this is complete, do a `Response.Redirect` to a new page `emailConfirmation.asp` which simply tells the user whether the email has been sent successfully or not (you could pass a success flag, and any other details required, through to it via Querystring or Session from `email.asp`).

Then, if `emailConfirmation.asp` is reloaded, no duplicate emails will be sent.

Comment: Yup, what he said: don't leave users on the page that actually sends stuff, because they ***will*** do something they're not supposed to. (And you can actually do this with a single ASP file; what's important is to do a Response.Redirect so that the form doesn't get submitted again.)